# Using GSON for JavaFX Objects

Tags: java, javafx, gson

I am using GSON to save / load.

One of my objects holds a `Label` and an `ImageView` (JavaFX objects).

It resulted me an overflow error.

JavaFX Controller class

```
   public void saveButtonAction(Event e) throws IOException {
            Gson output = new Gson();
            output.toJson(tile); //tile is an instance of Tile
    }
```

Tile Class

```
//Tile Class
public class Tile{
    private String type;
    private boolean hasMule;
    private Player owner;
    private ImageView image;
    private String production;
    private Label label;
    /** tile constructor
     * @param image image
     * @param label label
     */
    public Tile(ImageView image, Label label) {
        this.type = null;
        this.hasMule = false;
        this.owner = null;
        this.image = image;
        this.production = null;
        this.label = label;
    }
    /** set type of the tile
     * @param type type of the tile to be set
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        if (type != null) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
    /** set if tile has mule or not
     * @param hasMule boolean true if tile has mule or fasle if not
     */
    public void setHasMule(boolean hasMule) {
        this.hasMule = hasMule;
    }
    /** set owner to the tile
     * @param owner to be set as onwer for the tile
     */
    public void setOwner(Player owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    /** set the image to the tile
     * @param image to be set for the tile
     */
    public void setImage(ImageView image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    /** set production for the tile
     * @param production for the tile
     */
    public void setProduction(String production) {
        this.production = production;
    }
    /** get type of the tile
     * @return type of the tile
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    /** get if the tile has mule or not
     * @return boolean false if tile does not have mule, true otherwise
     */
    public boolean getHasMule() {
        return hasMule;
    }
    /** get owner of the tile
     * @return owner of the tile
     */
    public Player getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    /** get image
     * @return image of the tile
     */
    public ImageView getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    /** get production
     * @return production of the tile
     */
    public String getProduction() {
        return production;
    }

}
```

This is the error message that I got.

Could I ask why this is happening?

```
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
```

Comment: You need to post the code you wrote that resulted in this error.